# Combine Multiple primary databases to single AlwaysOn AG

Tags: availability-groups

Can i combine 2 different databases like db01 database from server1 and db02 database from server2 to single AG group on DR ?

Version : SQL server 2016 enterprise edition

Comment: This is a little unclear - could you add some more details on what you're trying to do please?

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot. This is because a database can belong to one and only one availability group.

You can, however, create an availability group from Server1 to DR and Server2 to DR which would have the DR server as a secondary to both availability groups and a copy of both databases would reside there.